# Incorrect playback resolution with OpenCV2(Python)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Recently I ran into a problem where the playback resolution from a simple OpenCV procedure is inflated from the original source.  Below is the code.  The original video is an MP4 with 694x1080 resolution.  When I run the script the frame width and height are listed as 704x1088.  Where did the extra pixels come from?  The only reason that I care is that I need to use a captured frame in a background subtraction and now the two images are different resolutions.  What is more confusing is that I didn't have problems with this on my home PC, only on my work PC (and I don't want to have to write two programs to accommodate both computers).  Finally the work PC plays the video at the correct resolution on VLC.  I really can't figure out where this is coming from or how to fix it.  Additionally the opencv is ignoring the .set function in the code.  Any ideas?

```
import cv2

video = cv2.VideoCapture('Fish_test1.mp4')
video.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 694)
video.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1080)
bg = cv2.imread('Background_image.jpg')
cv2.namedWindow('Video')


while (1):
    success, image = video.read()
    print(video.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH), video.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

    cv2.imshow('Video', image)
    cv2.imshow('BG', bg)

    k = cv2.waitKey(50)

    if k == 27:
        break
    if success == False:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I've just run into exactly the same issue...

Comment: Unfortunately no.  I still not sure what the issue was.  Sorry.